# Increase textblock size in memoir document

Tags: margins, memoir

I'm using the `memoir` document class to style my document. I'm using a two side layout. Now I simply want to increase the textblock width (in Figure 2.2 of documentation labeled with `\textwidth`). There are so many settings influencing this width and I'm a little bit lost how to start. I assume it is not enough to set `\textwidth` to a new value, right? Do I have to calculate all values manually? And if I have to calculate them, what are the best/correct scales to do that? When searching Tex SE, there are `pt`, `pb` etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to set the size of the text block. Either

- use the `\setXmarginsandblock{...}{...}{...}` (there are two) and remember `\checkandfixthelayout` afterwards

or

- use `\settypeblocksize{...}{...}{...}` plus the two `\setXmargins{...}{...}{...}` to set the size of the text block and place it on the 'paper'. Again remember the `\checkandfixthelayout`

Comment: Great, thank you! Two questions: 1) do you have a preference? 2) Is there a way to get the current values? I'm using \documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright,draft,a4paper]{memoir}

Comment: In the manual look in the boxes presenting the macros I mention. There the macros they change are listed. So if you wan to keep the height of the text block use `\settypeblocksize{\textheight}{...}{...}`. Preference no, it depends on the project. See also Peter Wilsons `memdesign` document on CTAN (or in your own installation), it explains a lot about book design any why certain margins have been used